# Makefile Recursion

Tags: shell, makefile

I'm currently working on a larger project than I have in the past, and so I'm organizing my files in a tree (see below)

```
Project
|            |-----Components|------folderb|-----asdf.cpp
|            |               |             |-----fdsa.cpp
|            |               |
|----- Source|               |------afolder|-----qwerty.cpp
|            |
|            |-----Include|-----bar.h
|                         |-----foo.h
|----- Bin
|
|----- Build
|
|----- Makefile
```

I'm still learning how to make makefiles, but I'm still getting a "doesn't match the target pattern" for the last few lines. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
##########################################
#           Editable options             #
##########################################
# Title
EXECUTABLE_NAME=net

# Compiler options
CC=g++
CFLAGS= -Wall
LDFLAGS= -Wall

# Folders
SRC_DIR=Source
BLD_DIR=Build
BIN_DIR=Bin
HDR_DIR=$(SRC_DIR)/Include

#########################################################
#                     Do Not Touch This                 #
#########################################################
SOURCE_FILES := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR)/ -type f -name '*.cpp')
SOURCE_FILE_NAMES := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR)/ -type f -name '*.cpp' -printf "%f\n")
HEADER_FILES := $(wildcard $(HDR_DIR)*.h)
OBJECT_FILES := $(SOURCE_FILE_NAMES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE_FILES = $(EXECUTABLE_NAME:%=$(BLD_DIR)/%)

build: $(EXECUTABLE_FILES)

clean:
    rm -r -f $(BIN_DIR)

.PHONY: build clean

$(EXECUTABLE_FILES): $(OBJECT_FILES)
    @$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
    @echo "Build successful!"

$(OBJECT_FILES): $(BIN_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/**/%.cpp
    @echo Compiling $^
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o -c $@ $^
```

Answer (score 0):

So the specific problem is here:

```
$(OBJECT_FILES): $(BIN_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/**/%.cpp
```

Your `$(OBJECT_FILES)` are going to be in the same directory as your source files, they'll include stuff like `Source/Components/afolder/qwerty.o`. But that doesn't match `Bin/%.o`, so that pattern rule doesn't apply. As such, you don't have a rule for building your objects. You'd just want `%.o : %.cpp` there.

---

Note also that you don't need to use the `shell` to get just the file names. You can use `$(notdir $(SOURCE_FILES))` for the same effect.

Also you're missing a `/` in your definition of `HEADER_FILES`